# Вывод информации из массива в виде списка

Tags: массивы, android, список

Есть код:

```
private void addTracks(String[] temp)
{
    if (temp != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        {
            if (trackChecker(temp[i]))
            {
                trackNames.add(temp[i]);
                trackArtworks.add(temp[i].substring(0, temp[i].length() - 4));
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Загружено " + Integer.toString(trackNames.size()) + " треков", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private boolean trackChecker(String trackToTest)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < EXTENSIONS.length; j++)
    {
        if (trackToTest.contains(EXTENSIONS[j]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы имена треков trackNames выводились в список, где ячейка для каждого элемента была findViewById(R.id.trackone)? Огромная просьба сделать ответ как можно более развёрнутым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Android ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)
- [List View](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
- [Список - ListView](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview)
- [на русском - ListView](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php)
- [A Simple Android ListView Example](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)
- [общая инфа](https://www.google.ru)